# How to define env values that start with dollar sign in php-fpm

Tags: php

I need to define a variable `SOMECONFIG` in php-fpm with a string `$hello` (a literal string that starts with a dollar sign)

If I put it like

```
env['SOMECONFIG']=$hello
```

It won't work because php-fpm will try to evaluate `$hello` from the environment variables which is not defined. The result of `$_SERVER['SOMECONFIG']` in php code will be an empty string.

What's strange about php-fpm is if the dollar sign is NOT at the beginning of the string, it can be defined without issues, the following works:

```
env['SOMECONFIG']=after$hello
```

I've also tried with `\$hello`, `$$hello`, `'$hello'`, or `"$hello"` without luck.

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you need the `$`?

Comment: I do, unfortunately.

Comment: wait.. are you asking why can't you assign a variable that doesn't exist to something?

Comment: @RicoChen what if you quote it then escape it (`"\$hello"`)?

Comment: @Script47 blank.

Comment: I don't understand what you're _actually_ trying to do: what's the result you're trying to achieve? Because php-fpm does not "try to evaluate $hello from the environment variables", it literally does what you tell it to, namely "assign the content of the variable `$hello` to the index `SOMECONFIG` of array `evt`" and so of course if $hello does not exist, that can't possibly work. So what are you actually trying to do? Assign a _string_, which should in this particular case be the string `"$hello"`,  to that array index?

Comment: Starting point for investigations: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/efed9f6b154029ad51a3d45c21dd31e89ec0295f/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_conf.c#L1098 - Not sure why the ini parser would try to handle arbitrary varnames, or unless SOMECONFIG refers to a core setting name. You should have gotten a log message if the string value was empty.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans my intention is very clear in my question, I just want to store the literal value of '$hello' into an environment variable SOMECONFIG which can be retrieved later using $_SERVER['SOMECONFIG']. What I expect is $_SERVER['SOMECONFIG'] will give me back '$hello'.

Comment: A similar question is asked here https://serverfault.com/questions/912596/how-to-escape-quote-a-dollar-sign-in-an-env-var-in-a-php-fpm-pool but unfortunately there aren't any answers yet. A limitation/bug of php-fpm I guess?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to escape it this way: `env['SOMECONFIG']="'$hello'"` and then retrieve the value in PHP using `str_replace` or `eval` ?

Comment: @RicoChen that is the opposite of clear. If you're working in PHP, `$hello` is not a literal value, it's a variable. If you want to put the _literal string_ `"$hello"` as content, then you (1) need to use the syntax for strings (i.e. quote the value) and (2) you can't add variable-likes using a single string except with single quotes, because if there is a token that _can_ be interpreted as variable then PHP by design _must_ evaluate it as a variable in active string mode. So either use `env["key"] = "$" . "hello";` or `env["key"] = '$hello';`

Comment: I would prefer not having to do any conversion in the application @CédricFrançoys

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I know the difference between a variable and a literal string. Your suggestion of using compose does not work. Did you mean to do that in the config file? I also updated my question a bit to make it clear $hello is a literal string, not a variable.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround.
Set the base64 encoded of "$hello" to an environment variable and decode it when use it.

in parameters.yml in Symfony3.4,
I was able to get the value like this:
%env(base64:SOMECONFIG)%

Comment: Thanks but 1) we are not using Symfony 2) I prefer not needing to do the conversion because that creates a variation in our code base, we have codes that already use  values directly from the env already.

Comment: Hiroshi H, actually this workaround should work. Using Symfony or not is irrelevant. Decoding base64 string in PHP should be trivial. I will accept your answer. Thanks.